# Emulate Word's use of double-quotes for writing upright mathematics in LyX?

Tags: lyx

*Written as Q&A after finding a solution.*

### The Problem

I want to use LyX for writing documents, but in Microsoft Word I like the behavior, where typing `x_"B" SPC` will produce *x*<sub>B</sub>, over typing something like `x_\mathrm  SPC B SPC SPC` for the same result in LyX. Can the behavior of word be emulated?

Comment: Nice problem/solution. I wonder if it would be easier to use a "LyX macro" for this. That would have the benefit that if you ever want to change from `\mathrm` to something else, it would be centralized and easy.

Comment: @scottkosty That depends on the use case, but for me most of the time it turns out to be over-engineering that bites me on collaborative documents / when copy/pasting content between documents. Also, any reasonable macro will still be long compared to `"B"`, since short macros (let's say `\r`) have a good chance of conflicting with builtin TeX things.

Comment: Good points, kdb!

Answer (score 1):

### The Solution

It turned out to be surprisingly straight-forward, except for caveats regarding the use of `"` to create quotes in the text.

To get the wanted behavior, you simply have to bind `"` to `font-roman` in the key binding  editor under *Tools > Preferences > Editing > Shortcuts*.

In the equation editor pressing `"` then switches to a `\mathrm` box, and pressing `"` again switches back out (as opposed to creating a nested "not mathrm" box). As a consequence, typing `x_"B" SPC` now has the exact same result as in Word.

### The Caveats

The rebinding process raised a couple of issues.

1. `"` can no longer be used to type double-quotes. I couldn't find a method to make `"` behave differently between text-mode and math-mode, but I need double-quotes much less frequently than `\mathrm`. My workaround was to just rebind `quote-insert` to `Ctrl+Shift+6`.
2. On non-English keyboards, it might not be possible to unter `"` as a key binding. On a German keyboard, typing `"` (= `Shift+2`) is registered as `Shift+"` and does not work. I solved this by reusing the predifined binding for `quote-insert`.
3. I first tried to rebind `quote-insert` to `Alt+"`, which by default is bound to `quote-insert inner`, which, in my setup, inserts single-quotes. Rebinding this to `quote-insert` *still* inserted inner-quotes. Hence the use of `Ctrl+Shift+6`.

## The Open Issue

Ideally, `"` would behave as `font-roman` in math mode and as `quote-insert` in text-mode. I could not yet find a way to make that work.

## For completeness: LaTeX solution

The same can be achieved for L<sup>A</sup>T<sub>E</sub>X, but there it requires redefining " in a way that wouldn't display correctly in LyX's equation editor due to stateful logic. Use with care, as it may annoy collaborators on documents.

```
\catcode`\"=\active
\newif\ifquoterm
\def "{\ifmmode\ifquoterm \it\quotermfalse \else \rm\quotermtrue \fi \else \string"\fi}
```

[image]